# Are there any working examples of how to use the scikit-build with f2py?

Tags: python, cmake, f2py

The scikit-build distribution provides usage examples of FindF2PY and UseF2PY, but they are incomplete, only providing a partial CMakeLists.txt file without the other required files. Based on the documentation I have not been able to make something that builds.

Following the examples in the scikit-build documentation, I created the following files:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

project(skbuild_test)

enable_language(Fortran)

find_package(F2PY REQUIRED)

add_f2py_target(f2py_test f2py_test.f90)
add_library(f2py_test MODULE f2py_test.f90)
install(TARGETS f2py_test LIBRARY DESTINATION f2py_test)
```

setup.py:

```
import setuptools
from skbuild import setup

requires=['numpy']

setup(
    name="skbuild-test",
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Performs line integrals through SAMI3 grids',
    author='John Haiducek',
    requires=requires,
    packages=['f2py_test']
)
```

f2py_test.f90:

```
module mod_f2py_test
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine f2py_test(a,b,c)
    real(kind=8), intent(in)::a,b
    real(kind=8), intent(out)::c
  end subroutine f2py_test
end module mod_f2py_test
```

In addition, I created a directory f2py_test containing an empty **init**.py.

The output from `python setup.py develop` shows that scikit-build invokes CMake and compiles my Fortran code. However, it fails to find Python.h while compiling the f2py wrapper code:

```
[2/7] Building C object CMakeFiles/_f2...kages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/_f2py_runtime_library.dir/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c.o 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -O3 -DNDEBUG -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/_f2py_runtime_library.dir/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/_f2py_runtime_library.dir/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/_f2py_runtime_library.dir/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c.o   -c ../../../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c
In file included from ../../../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c:2:
../../../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.h:7:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include "Python.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

First caveat, there may be a better way to do this, as I just figured out how to make scikit-build work by stumbling on your post and looking at documentation. Second caveat, I'm also learning cmake. So, there may be a better way.

There are a couple of things that you'll need to make your example here work. The big one is the second argument of add_f2py_target() isn't the source file. It is either the name of a pre-generated *.pyf, or to let f2py generate one, provide it an argument without the *.pyf extension. The other is adding the include directories for various components.

I made your example work with the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(skbuild_test)
enable_language(Fortran)
find_package(F2PY REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS NumPy)

#the following command either generates or points to an existing .pyf
#if provided an argument with .pyf extension, otherwise f2py generates one (not source code).
add_f2py_target(f2py_test f2py_test)
add_library(f2py_test MODULE f2py_test.f90)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${_Python3_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(f2py_test ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
install(TARGETS f2py_test LIBRARY DESTINATION f2py_test)
```